# MATLAB: findpeaks function

Tags: matlab

I'm using MATLAB 2013a and trying to find peak points of my data. When I tried code example given in 
[Find Peaks with Minimum Separation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html#bufhyo1-1)

I am getting the following error:

```
Error using uddpvparse (line 122)
Invalid Parameter/Value pairs.

Error in findpeaks>parse_inputs (line 84)
hopts = uddpvparse('dspopts.findpeaks',varargin{:});

Error in findpeaks (line 59)
[X,Ph,Pd,Th,Np,Str,infIdx] = parse_inputs(X,varargin{:});
```

I tried simple x and y vectors and got the same error. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem as you (R2013a on OSX) with the example by the Mathworks. For some reason it seems we can't use `findpeaks` with the x-and y-data as input arguments, We need to call the function with the y data and use the `[peaks,locations]` output to get the peaks/plot them.

It looks like in [R2014b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/release-notes.html) they changed some stuff about `findpeaks` that does not work with older versions...like calling the function with not output argument in R2014b plots the data/peaks without any additional step...but it does not for earlier versions.

Anyhow here is a way to workaround the problem. Call `findpeaks` with a single input argument (y data that is, you can use property/value pairs as well) and use the indices (locations) to show the peaks:

```
clc
clear

load sunspot.dat

year = sunspot(:,1);
avSpots = sunspot(:,2);


[peaks, locations] = findpeaks(avSpots)

plot(year,avSpots)

hold on

scatter(year(locations),avSpots(locations),40,'filled')
hold off
```

Output:

[image]

It might be worthwhile to contact The Mathworks about this. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help, is there any website for finding the differences between MATLAB versions?

Comment: You can access the release notes from The Mathworks in the link I provided above (click on R2014b you will get there). And you're welcome!

Comment: Oh I didn't see it :) Thank you again.